# Can a person escape the Twilight Zone?

Tags: the-twilight-zone

I'm not sure how it's supposed to work. Is everyone "stuck" in the Twilight Zone, yet strange things happen to only a small percentage of the population? Can people escape from the Twilight Zone?

Comment: I always thought it was just a metaphor.

Comment: It's not an actual zone dude.

Comment: Have you ever watched the show?

Comment: Has anyone ever stepped beyond the show's forth wall is a valid question.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "escape". Some people do get back to their normal life, usually by learning some some lesson or reaching some kind of wisdom. And some "escape" by leaving this world and passing on to a higher plane.

Comment: One interpretation is that the 'zone is some higher being - aliens? God? the universe? Q? - grabbing random samples of humanity and testing us, sometimes to destruction.

Comment: Yeah, it's more like... the vicinity of an area, adjacent to a location. A scenic route through a state recreational area known as the human mind.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but isn't Twilight zone the movie of the vampire, wolf-guy and the chick with no-expressions on her face. Man, if you are in that zone, you need to get out... :D

Comment: Several people "escaped the Twilight Zone", in the old episodes.

Comment: @Mazura That might be a valid question, but that's not what this question is asking.

Comment: @Axelrod I disagree. The people don't start out in the real world and then enter the twilight zone. They're always in the twilight zone. They might start or end in a normal-looking **part** of the twilight zone. It's not actually a physical zone, just a metaphor for imagination and story telling. All of these characters exist only in the stories and our imaginations, so they're always in the twilight zone. Unless they crawl through your television and enter the real world, they never leave the twilight zone. But if that happens, maybe it's you who entered the twilight zone.

Comment: @KevinWorkman And I disagree with that being the sum total, because the show itself treats being in the Twilight Zone as a condition. When the crazy happenings stop and a person is allowed to live their lives normally again, they are said to have survived/escaped -- the Twilight Zone.

Answer (score 8):

The Twilight Zone is not a physical place, but Serling's term to describe the "dimension of imagination", where anything is possible, and your question assumes that only bad things can happen there.

By that yardstick, anyone dealing with a fantastic situation would be in the Twilight Zone.  Whether that occurs in a place that couldn't possibly exist (asteroids with atmosphere, for instance), or whether that occurs someplace on Earth in a quaint little suburb normal in every other respect, that person could be said to be in the Zone.

The show in many episodes draws intentional parallels to the real world.  If you're confused about what the episodes consider real and what the episode considers imagination, that's probably the point, and the creators would consider that a job well done.  You're thinking about it, mission accomplished.  It's not supposed to be a line drawn or a distinct border.

There are episodes where escape from the situation is definitely something to accomplish and go for ("Nick of Time", "A Penny for Your Thoughts").  There are others where, for the characters, imagination *is the escape* and that can be a good or bad thing ("The Sixteen Millimeter Shrine", "A World of Difference", "A Stop at Willoughby", "The Bewitching Pool", so many others).  Others, escape is impossible ("Time Enough At Last", "Elegy") or the unreal situation is made worse by the nature of the characters in it ("Monsters are Due on Maple Street", "Escape Clause". again many many others).

While the plot twist that screws over the characters is a common bit on The Twilight Zone (although if you want a show that *loves* that bit, try the Outer Limits from the 1990s), that doesn't mean the Zone is a physical place that everyone needs to escape, nor that everything you see is completely in the realm of the unreal.

Answer (score 1):

It varies per episode. In [Little Girl Lost](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734585/), with the girl who fell through her bedroom wall into another dimension, the hole closed up right after her father saved her. In [Stopover in a Quiet Town](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734625/), the one with the partying couple that wound up as toys for the giant boy, they clearly spent the rest of their lives in his toy town, unless they killed themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this logic: these people don't start out in the real world and then enter the twilight zone. They're always in the twilight zone. As others have mentioned, that's the whole point. It's not actually a physical zone, but just a metaphor for imagination and story telling. All of these characters exist only in the stories and our imaginations, so they're always in the twilight zone.

Comment: Look at the two examples I cited. I guess you have to assume they existed prior to the start of the story. The little girl was an ordinary girl before the story began. Then a dimensional rift opened off of her bedroom. Then things went back to normal. The nasty couple was at a party and passed out in a bedroom. They assumed when they work up (with a hangover) that they were in a back room of the house they were partying at. Only certain stories could be seen as taking place completely in the Twilight Zone.